# List Python Problems

Tags: python, list

I just started learning Python and I encountered this problem:

```
a = [0, 1]
b = [a]
print(a, b) 

a.pop()
print(a, b)
```

Result:

```
[0, 1] [[0, 1]]
[0] [[0]]
```

Why does this happen and how do I avoid it? I want b = [0, 1]. As far as I understood, the b[0] was linked to a so I used `b[a.copy()]`. Thanks guys.

Comment: `b = a[:]` OR `b=list(a)`

Comment: ie. `b = a.copy()`

Comment: Do you know what is this topic called? Is it memory allocation in Python?

Comment: test code on https://pythontutor.com to see how it uses reference.

Comment: It is called variable initialization.. you can search for how to initialize a list..

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Python,

if you want all elements of `a`to be passed to `b` you can *dump* them like this:

```
b = [*a] # is the same as [a[0], a[1], ...... ]
```

which will lead to `b = [0,1]`